# Does Windows 10 have a built-in SSH server?

Tags: ssh, powershell, windows-10

Does the release version of Windows 10, [as](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/06/02/openssh_windows/) [rumored](http://thenextweb.com/microsoft/2015/06/03/windows-will-soon-support-the-ssh-encryption-protocol-for-remote-access/), have built-in SSH server functionality? If so, how do I go about enabling it?

Comment: The SSH is rumored for PowerShell, I don't think it is tied to the Windows 10 release. I haven't seen any news about a PowerShell update yet.

Comment: They added it in the Fall Creator Update and you can add both the client and/or the server by going to (Settings > Apps > Manage optional features > Add a feature) and install it. Note, that it still bears the (beta) tag but I have used it and works effectively no different than Putty.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Short answer:** Not yet, but it's coming.

**Long answer:**  It's not actually part of Windows 10, but rather a new feature Microsoft is adding to PowerShell.  Microsoft is working with and beginning to contribute to the OpenSSH project.  This will effectively put an SSH server on Windows but you'll have to turn it on and have the latest version of PowerShell.  I have not heard any release date for PowerShell with the OpenSSH functionality mentioned yet.

Additional reading [arstechnica.com](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/06/microsoft-bringing-ssh-to-windows-and-powershell/)

Official Microsoft Announcement [msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2015/06/03/looking-forward-microsoft-support-for-secure-shell-ssh.aspx)

Comment: It's been almost a year. Is it still coming? If it has already arrived, some links how to enable it would be very helpful.

Comment: This answer is no longer correct. James Gibbons answer below is accurate as of the Windows 10 "Anniversary Update" that went out around August 1st.

Comment: @ScottRFrost, this answer is correct; the SSH broker/proxy services are unrelated, and of limited use. They're intended for developer mode testing of [UWP app deployment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development#ssh).

Answer (score 4):

Update:  The newest technical preview versions of Windows 10 Anniversary update have two services "SSH Server Broker" and "SSH Server Proxy". These are both built-in to windows 10 Build 14366 and above. It is still unclear about the client however and I have been looking unsuccessfully for Microsoft documentation about these two services...

Comment: I can verify 2 weeks after your post there seems to be no documentation on `SSH Server Broker` or `SSH Server Proxy` available from Microsoft or anywhere else, I've gotten sshd up and running via `Cygwin` in the past but not sure how to do it via `Bash on Ubuntu on Windows`.

Comment: I don't know about the documentation but on my system with the Windows 10 Anniversary update ssh is listening on port 22 and I can authenticate using my Windows user account and get a CMD shell environment.

Comment: These broker and proxy services are unrelated to the planned SSH server for Windows. They're used with Windows 10 developer mode enabled in order to [deploy UWP apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development#ssh).

Comment: The fall creators update seems to have added the OpenSSH server and client as optional features. Settings > Apps & features > Manage optional features > Add a feature. In the list are OpenSSH Server and Client entries. Both marked beta. I installed the client, but had to reboot before the ssh command was available from PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

Can confirm and adding to the answer from James Gibbons (can't comment):

*SSH Server Broker* and *SSH Server Proxy* are 2 new services present on Windows 10 Anniversary (can be found at running `services.msc` from command prompt or pressing win+r). This service is not running under the (Ubuntu) Linux Subsystem for Windows.

If enabled port 22 is open and you can login with a local user. The user must be in the *Ssh Users* group. With a Microsoft account the username is the one displayed at `lusrmgr.msc`

Configuration for this can be found at the registry on:

- `HKLM/System/CurrentControlSet/Control/Ssh/Broker`
- `HKLM/System/CurrentControlSet/Control/Ssh/Sftp`

Both of which are read-only except for TrustedInstaller. The configuration seems to be similar to OpenSSH since Microsoft is building a custom implementation for Windows. I also found this from the Microsoft Powershell Github repository on OpenSSH on installing OpenSSH:

https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH