# How to set up a secure ssh server on Windows 10?

Tags: networking, windows-10, ssh, security

I am running a Windows 10 VM as a guest on a Mac host. I would like to be able to ssh into the Windows guest using ssh keys. I have found various resources, most notably [this one](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/how-to-win10-ssh-service) which is great, but the author suggests using strong passwords and I prefer ssh keys. Is there a canonical method for setting up a secure* ssh server on Windows? I need the Windows guest to have full network access, so isolating it isn't an option for me.

*I understand that an open port is inherently less secure, but I feel comfortable enough if the only way in is with a private/public pair. I'm just not experienced enough to confidently do this manually, and am looking for a well beaten path.

Comment: Related: [Does Windows 10 have a built-in SSH server?](https://superuser.com/questions/950117/does-windows-10-have-a-built-in-ssh-server)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a canonical method for setting up a secure* ssh server on
>   Windows?

This requires third-party software to accomplish.

Additionally, as pointed out by the article you linked to in your question, the following is true with regards to `Microsoft SSH Server for Windows` which is the name of the service you described in the article.

> Microsoft’s SSH Server is not a full SSH server implementation and is
>   meant to be used for cross-device communication for development
>   purposes. It doesn’t support all SSH authentication methods and
>   features like compression and multiplexing.

[Source](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/how-to-win10-ssh-service)

Comment: Alternative Solution: [SSH into Windows 10 using key pairs](https://superuser.com/questions/1161138/ssh-into-windows-10-using-key-pairs?rq=1)